# Web scraping nested tables with python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is my first messages, I am a noob on the field. I tried to get hints around to solve my problem, but I have a last issue. I would be also grateful if you can make prettier my code if needed.

In short, i want to get a list of values from a website to write them on an excel file. In the example, the list is names and numbers in the central table (from "Buffon" to "Totale" not included). With my code i could get all the values, and a bit more, but every value "owns" a line while i would like to have the values in the same lines as in the website's table.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'http://calcio-seriea.net/presenze/1998/1150/'
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

job_elems = soup.findAll('table' ,{'class': 'ContentObjectBottom'})[2].findAll('td', {'class': 'TableCellBorder'})

for job_elem in job_elems:
        print(job_elem.text)
```

Moreover, the website is full of nested tables with no distinctive identifications or classes. I did what i thought was the best. Hope it is good enough to work on. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_html("http://calcio-seriea.net/presenze/1998/1150/")[6]

print(df)
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```